# Merge html coverage reports from two different frameworks generated from coverage.py

Tags: python, coverage.py

I have two different automation framework in python for my test cases
Framework-1-is old and is going to be deprecated 
Framework-2-is New one with enhanced capabilities

for time being i wanted to merge coverage HTML report generate by both framework till the time all TC's from framework will get ported to framework 2
Is there anything available ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't merge the HTML reports, but you could combine the data files from the two test runs (using the `coverage combine` command), and then generate an HTML report from the combined data.